Asymptotic properties of integral of power of sine function?
I'm trying to investigate the asymptotic property of the following integral:
$$
    \int_0^{\theta} \sin^nx dx, \quad n\to +\infty
$$
where $\theta \in (0,\pi/2)$ is a constant.
For the case $\theta = \pi/2$, it is the Wallis integral and we have
$$
    \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^nx dx \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}.
$$
But for the case when $\theta \in (0,\pi/2)$, I have no idea how to analyse it.

If $W_n$ denotes the above integral, then it satisfies the recursive relation $$ W_{n} = \frac{n-1}{n}W_{n-2}-\frac{1}{n}(\sin{\theta})^{n-1}\cos{(\theta)}$$

Yes, but I cannot derive an asymptotic limit from this recursive relation...

If "$\theta$ is not too close to $\frac\pi2$" (the analysis of what it means can be done)
$$I_n=\int_0^\theta \sin^nx dx=\int_0^\theta \sin^n(\theta-x) dx=\int_0^\theta e^{n\ln(\sin\theta\cos x-\sin x\cos\theta)} dx$$$$=\sin^{n}\theta\int_0^\theta e^{\ln(\cos x-\cot\theta\sin x)}dx$$
Decomposing $\cos x, \sin x$ near the maximum of the integrand (at $x=0$) and expanding integration to $\infty$
$$I_n\sim \sin^n\theta\int_0^\infty e^{n\ln(1-\cot\theta ,x)}dx\sim\sin^n\theta\int_0^\infty e^{-n\cot\theta ,x}dx=\frac{\sin^{n+1}\theta}{n\cos\theta}$$

Thanks! I don't understand how the second line of equation 1 is derived. And what the "$\theta$ is not too closed to $\frac{\pi}{2}$" is used.

My apology, there was a typo
$$I_n=\int_0^\theta\sin^nxdx=\int_0^\theta\sin^n(\theta-x)dx=\sin^n\theta\int_0^\theta e^{\color{red}{n}\ln(\cos\theta-\cot\theta\sin x)}dx$$
$$=\sin^n\theta\int_0^\theta e^{n\ln(1-\frac{x^2}2-\cot\theta, x+...)}dx=\frac{\sin^n}n\theta\int_0^\theta e^{-\cot\theta,t-\frac{t^2}{2n}+...}dt$$
We can drop the second term in the power of the exponent, if $\cot\theta\gg\frac1n$. Taking $\theta=\frac\pi2-\epsilon$, we get the condition "$\theta$ not too close to $\frac\pi2$" as $\epsilon\gg\frac1n$

Better is: $$I_n \sim \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sin ^{n+1}(\theta ) e^{\frac{1}{2} n \cos ^2(\theta )} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{n} \cos (\theta
)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}$$

@MariuszIwaniuk. How did you obtain this nice form ? Cheers :-)

Denote
$$I_n \equiv \int_0^\theta\sin^nxdx$$
When $\theta \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, consider the sequence
$$\frac{n+1}{\sin^n\theta}I_n = (n+1)\int_0^\theta\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sin \theta}\right)^ndx$$
and use the substitution $u = \left(\frac{\sin x}{\sin \theta}\right)^{n+1}$
$$\frac{n+1}{\sin^n\theta}I_n = \int_0^1\frac{\sin\theta \:du}{\cos\left(\sin^{-1}\left(u^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\sin\theta\right)\right)}\longrightarrow \tan\theta $$
as $n\to\infty$ by dominated convergence. Thus we have the asymptotic
$$I_n \sim \sec\theta\cdot\frac{\sin^{n+1}\theta}{n+1}$$

@Svyatoslav thank you for the catch, I missed a chain rule

Just out of curiosity : how did you get this clever idea ? Cheers :-)

Using
$$I_n= \int_0^\theta \sin^n(x)\,dx=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \sin^n(x)\,dx-\int_\theta^{\frac \pi 2} \sin^n(x)\,dx $$ The first integral is
$$I_1=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \sin^n(x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\,\,\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}$$
Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function, the second is
$$I_2=\int_\theta^{\frac \pi 2} \sin^n(x)\,dx= \cos (\theta ) \,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos ^2(\theta )\right)=$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(k-\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2 k+1)\,\, \Gamma (k+1)\,\, \Gamma \left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)} \,\,\cos^{2n+1}(\theta)$$
Except for $I_1$, I have not been able to find  proper asymptotics.
